# How to find what makes Windows Installer pop up

Tags: c++, installation, windows-installer

I have a windows application that we bundle with Wise installer to create a MSI package. At a precise point (always the same), there is a windows installer pop up that tries to fetch new stuff from the msi package.

Everything is already there, because if we cancel the installation the application still runs correctly.

How can I find out what is needed and what prompts the msi package installer?

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens when installed resources are missing. To find the exact cause you can try this:

- after receiving a “preparing to install” message open Event Viewer (you can search it in the Start menu or launch “eventvwr.msc”)
- go to “Windows Logs” -> “Application”
- look for “MsiInstaller” information messages which have this form:

> Event Type: Warning
>
> Event Source: MsiInstaller
>
> Event ID: 1001
>
> Description: Detection of product
>   '{1F7D16F0-836D-4CE4-9123-D30B2F24A17B}', feature 'FeatureId' failed
>   during request for component '{068153F4-B9E0-4745-9A47-833764D9D60C}'

The GUIDs will be different on your machine, but they can help you identify which component is causing the problem. The first GUID is your package ProductCode and the second one is for the problematic component. You can try creating an installation log and see why the component is not installed.

Basically, files and registry entries installed by your package should not be moved, removed or renamed after installation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It tells me that the component being installed is VC++ redistributable. Do you know how I can resolve those guids?

Comment: Can you give me more details? What redistributable? Is it a prerequisite file, a merge module file or a file in your package? How does it get removed after install?